# Covariant derivative of the variation of the metric

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, covariance

Say you are varying some function (it could be a tensor, or a tensor density, scalar, etc.) that depends on the metric (the metric is what is varying), so you have

$\delta f = \frac{\partial f}{\partial g_{\mu\nu}}\delta g_{\mu\nu}$.

Now say that I want to take a covariant derivative of this thing. Is

$\nabla_\alpha \delta g_{\mu\nu}=0$?

Certainly the metric is constant with respect to covariant derivatives. But I'm not sure about the variation of the metric.

If the variation is arbitrary, I'd have to say no (it's just some symmetric tensor). If the variation is due to a diffeomorphism or a coordinate transformation, I'm not sure. Does anybody know of a good answer to this question? A reference to some authoritative work would be very useful.

Comment: If $\nabla\delta g=0$ the Euler-Lagrange equations of the Einstein-Hilbert action would be very different from the standard Einstein field equations.

Comment: It seems OP has basically answered his own question.